# Why are all random numbers generated between lowest() and max() equal to infinity?

Tags: c++, c++11, random

Why is `u` in the program below always infinity?

```
#include <random>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    auto seed = std::random_device()();
    std::mt19937 randomEngine(seed);
    const double lo = std::numeric_limits<double>::lowest(); // ~= -1.8e+308
    const double hi = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(); // ~= 1.8e+308
    std::uniform_real_distribution<> U(lo, hi);
    double u = U(randomEngine); // always 1.#INF000000000000
    return 0;
}
```

It's clearly something to do with the range passed to `std::uniform_real_distribution`. If I pass it `(lo,0)` or `(0,hi)` it generates finite random numbers, but why?

Comment: Hmya, don't do that.  The lo..hi range cannot be expressed in a floating pointer number, the overflow is going to trip infinity.  This quacks heavily like a XY Problem, what kind of algorithm thinks that 1.8E+308 is a useful random number but 2.0E+308 is not?

Comment: @HansPassant thankyou, and re the XY problem, this is a minimal example that demonstrates a problem I found when trying to write a test program for the question [Test the randomness (uniformly distributed) on a 64 bit float random generator](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92984/test-the-randomness-uniformly-distributed-on-a-64-bit-float-random-generator) on stats.se.

Comment: @HansPassant, maybe make your comment an answer instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to [**N3797**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf):

**26.5.8.2.2 [rand.dist.uni.real]**

> 2 Requires: `a ≤ b` and `b − a ≤ numeric_limits<RealType>::max()`.

This condition is not met since `b - a` is `2 * numeric_limits<double>::max()`.